# sqldatasource default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqldatasource

How do I set the default value of a SQLdatasource parameter to the select all

```
<asp:Parameter Name="original_lastsaved" Type="string" defaultvalue="???"/>
```

Thanks for the help.
saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like...

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["original_lastsaved"].DefaultValue = "Set Value here";
```

**Edit:** If you want that when you click the `Select All` button, it will pick up all of the record and ignore the `where clause parameter`, then make an overloaded with no parameter and then `clear the Select parameter` in `SQLDataSource Selecting event`. e.g.

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: sorry you got my question wrong . i mean if parameter value is empty suppose in control parameter then how will i show all the records.

Comment: hmm.it might work . but i already got a simple solution for that simply set the default value as '%'.sorry for sharing the answer late