# Repeater control search

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
 SELECT * FROM [License] WHERE ([LicenseID] = @LicenseID)
```

This is the code i placed in the repeater sqldatasource.If I  type license id 1 in textbox,i can see the values connected to License id 1 in the repeater.

How can i place an if statement in the sqldatasource so that on page load i can see all details of the table License in the repeater  and if search button is pressed  after typing license id in the textbox ,then values related to that specific license id will be shown.

Thanks EDIT Iam trying the way you said Gurdien BUT

```
  SELECT * FROM License WHERE (0 = @selectAll OR LicenseID=@LicenseID) -> Not working 

   SELECT * FROM License WHERE (0 = @selectAll ) ->working

   SELECT * FROM License WHERE (LicenseID=@LicenseID)-> working
```

On pageload i want to show all fields and on typing licenseid in the textbox i wnat to show that specific licenceid details.

Comment: You should at least show your sqldatasource  control if you use one. Otherwise i would simply suggest to remove the filter if it's not a postback.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["LicenseID"].DefaultValue="*";
```

on your page load.

And make sure that you write it inside `!ispostback`

Similar question on SO:- [sqldatasource default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596783/sqldatasource-default-value)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there'll be other ways around for this, but this is the nearest I can think of.

First, modify your query like this...

`SELECT * FROM License WHERE ([LicenseID] = @LicenseID OR 1 = @selectAll )`

Then, somewhere inside the page, create a hidden field by dragging from the toolbox. 
Set the source of your second parameter, `@selectAll`, to the value of that hidden field. Set the default value of the param property to 1. 
Whenever the user click the Search button, set the value of the hidden field to 0. Or, whatever you prefer to. 
I'm sure you are setting the param source of `@LicenseID` to the value of the text box.

I think you're getting the idea of this. 
By default, your query will look like this...

`SELECT * FROM License WHERE ([LicenseID] = '' OR 1 = 1 )`

So, even there aren't any value for `LicenseID  = ''`, the condition `1 = 1` will always return true. So, you will get all the data from the table. 
When the user typed into the text box, the value of the hidden field will change to, let's say, 0, your query will become like this...

`SELECT * FROM License WHERE ([LicenseID] = '00112233' OR 1 = 0 )`

Although the second condition, `1 = 0` will return false, the rest of the query will work accordingly based on your value with the LicenseID you typed in.

You can set the hidden field value back to 1, when the user clear the text box, or by clicking some reset button. So that, the query will reset back to select all mode.

Wish you good luck...!